# Virtual subdirectory redirect

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, statistics

I'm relatively new to .htaccess files and redirection, so I'm just wondering how I would go about creating virtual subdirectories for every user. Basically I want

```
domain.com/user/batman
```

to redirect to

```
domain.com/stats.php?user=batman
```

Thanks.

Comment: Ask this kind of question in server fault.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rule to your `.htaccess` in web root "/"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/?$ stats.php?user=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```